# My dropdown menu shows all of the options separately, how to fix it?

Tags: php, html, forms, loops, drop-down-menu

I am populating data from the Database to view nationalities in a drop-down menu. However, I am getting each nationality separately as [attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sspIJ.png). I believe there is a small mistake with the select or option but I could not recognize it.

This is the current code causing the error in screenshot provided:

```
$acs = $user->getallnationality();
  echo'<option value="" selected disabled>Select Nationality</option>';
foreach ($acs as $nationalityData) {

        echo'<select> <option  value="' . $nationalityData->nationality . '">' . $nationalityData->nationality . '</option> </select>' ;
    }
```

I have tried removing the `.$nationalityData->nationality` but still does not work correctly.

Would appreciate if someone can help me fix this to have a single drop-down-menu with all of these nationalities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not just outputting an `<option>` for each item in `$nationalityData`, you're outputting an entire `<select>`. You just need to move that tag outside the loop.

```
$acs = $user->getallnationality();
echo '<select><option value="" selected disabled>Select Nationality</option>';
foreach ($acs as $nationalityData) {
    echo '<option>' . $nationalityData->nationality . '</option>' ;
}
echo '</select>';
```

By the way, if you're using the same value for the option value and option text, you can omit the value attribute and the option text will be used as the value.